# Im using method invoker to remove my usercontrol but when i use foreach its count was always less by 1

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void Invoke()
{
     try
     {
         if (this.InvokeRequired)
         {
            this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { Invoke(); }));
         }
         else
         {
            removeUc();
         }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
        XtraMessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
     }
}
```

this is my invoke function im using this because it came from another thread sorry im new here.

```
private void removeUc()
{
     foreach (UserControl uc in fPanel.Controls)
     {
         fPanel.Controls.Remove(uc);
     }
}
```

and this is my remove function, my problem is for example i have 3 usercontrol yet it only remove 2 it always leaves one usercontrol i want to remove all

Comment: you cant remove elements of a collection while iterating over them over a foreach loop. your removeUc method should raise an exception

Comment: can you show an example so I can see how it was done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void removeUc()
{
     var forRemoval = new List<UserControl>();
     //Create removal list
     foreach (UserControl uc in fPanel.Controls)
     {
         forRemoval.Add(uc);
     }
     //remove from fpanel
     foreach (UserControl uc in forRemoval)
     {
         fPanel.Controls.Remove(uc);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The general rule for such situations (language-agnostic) is:

- **If the collection is known to be array** or array-like, i.e. accessible by index, and `remove` shifts indices of all following items:

  *→ then you just iterate it backwards (with `for` not `foreach`)*.
- **If the collection is iterable** but assumptions about internal data structure cannot be made:

  *→ then you create a list/array of elements to be removed,
     then remove them in a second loop (like in apomene's answer).*